# Eclipse ignoring Maven test-scoped dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependency-management

I have a Maven project which uses SLF4J. For the purpose of running it from Eclipse, I want log output to go to the console, so I have configured dependencies as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
```

That is, I am pulling in `slf4j-simple` with a `test` scope.

The project is a library. In its `test` folder there is a class with a `main` method which runs some tests and diagnostic functions. When I run it that way from Eclipse, SLF4J logs to `System.err` as expected.

When I use the library project in another (whose main class is in the project’s `src` folder), SLF4J complains with the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I have tried adding the same dependencies to the parent project, to no avail. However, if I change the scope for `slf4j-simple` to `compile` or `runtime` in the parent project, logging works as expected.

What is happening here? Does this behavior have anything to do with the source tree in which the main class resides (`test` implying I am testing, thus test-scoped dependencies are pulled in, `src` implies regular runtime and test-scoped dependencies are not available)? If so, how do I tell my toolchain that I want `slf4j-simple` when running in Eclipse, but some other backend when building a JAR for deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether Eclipse uses test or runtime dependencies is governed by a project setting. To change it, go to **Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Source**. **Contains test sources** (a child of your project) is the setting you are looking for. If set to **Yes**, Eclipse will use test-scoped dependencies, else it will not.

Yes seems to be the default for a project which has code in the `test` tree, No for all others.

Change the setting as needed, apply, close and run—Eclipse will give you the desired set of dependencies.

There may be other relevant settings I have overlooked—feel free to drop a comment in this case.